# I have an error when using Celery and AWS Elasticache redis as a broker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, celery, amazon-elasticache

I try to run celery using Elasticache as a broker for tasks and I've got an error `CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot`.
Has anybody faced this error and resolved it?
By the way, does the last version of celery supports Elasticache redis clusters?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWYeR.jpg

I've tried to use redis-py-cluster but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.